# Check if the file is downloading in Chrome with the api

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have planned to develop a Google Chrome extension which act as a download manager ie. when a user downloads any item from the browser the extension must catch it and display its downloading progress at the top.

So I have done with two fles named `manifest.json` and `popup.html`.

## manifest.json

The main file which comes in action

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "One-click Kittens",
 "description": "something",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
"<all_urls>",
"downloads"
  ],

 "content_scripts": [
{

  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["myscript.js"]
}
  ],





 "browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

## popup.html

The file which act as a popup which appears on the sidebar of the Chrome.

```
  <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(!Modernizr.meter){
            alert('Sorry your brower does not support HTML5 progress bar');
        } else {
            var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
                max = progressbar.attr('max'),
                time = (1000/max)*5,    
                value = progressbar.val();

            var loading = function() {
                value += 1;
                addValue = progressbar.val(value);

                $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

                if (value == max) {
                    clearInterval(animate);                    
                }
            };

            var animate = setInterval(function() {
                loading();
            }, time);
        };
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
        <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## myscript.js

```
<script>
var c = chrome.downloads.search({query: }, function(results){
            var formattedResults = [];
            for(var i in results) {

                chrome.downloads.download(
                    {
                        method: "POST",
                        filename: results[i]
                    }, function () {
                        if(results[i] == undefined ) {
                            console.log('files arent located');
                        } else {
                            console.log('its downloading');
                        }



)

})

</script>
```

## The problems that I face

1. When I run the popup.js in the manifest file it doesn't show me the progress (ie. value incrementation) but it works just fine when I run it separately.
2. I just want to able to detect the file in which the user has downloaded and display its progress on popup.html.

I have tried [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) but it didn't help. Maybe it's because I am not an expert in Google apis.

Comment: I've never done extension development, but looks like you need to checkout the downloadItem type. It has a bytesReceived and fileSize property. It doesn't look like the onChanged method supports bytesReceived, but there must be some other way to bind an event to the amount of data downloaded. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged

Comment: @GrahamT i have checked it out ..but i dont know how to start ..i want the user to download the selected item..from the page ..i dont want to bind an item in downloads api

Comment: @AvinashBabu any luck with the code I provided?

Comment: @JSuar no it doesnt ..:(

Comment: @AvinashBabu did you look at the rest of the Download Manager Button code?

Comment: @JSuar yeah ..i have made some modifications on the code ..and i am trying to add sound after the download is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out Google's example extensions that use the chrome.downloads api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:download). For example, as Graham T suggested, you could probably use the [onChanged event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged) which is used by the following example extension: [Download and Open Button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/downloads/download_open.zip) and [Download Manager Button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/downloads/download_manager.zip).

**chrome.downloads**

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads
- Use the chrome.downloads API to programmatically initiate, monitor, manipulate, and search for downloads.

From Download Manager Button:

```
DownloadItem.prototype.onChanged = function(delta) {
  for (var key in delta) {
    if (key != 'id') {
      this[key] = delta[key].current;
    }
  }
  this.render();
  if (delta.state) {
    setLastOpened();
  }
  if ((this.state == 'in_progress') && !this.paused) {
    DownloadManager.startPollingProgress();
  }
};
```

I recommend looking at the rest of the sample code as it should be clearer on how to properly use chome.downloads.

Comment: Yes, `this` is a `DownloadItem` object. More info on the object here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem